# How can a marginnote be inside textwidth?

Tags: margins, geometry, marginnote

Possibly, I ask the wrong question. What I would like to achieve is to have my notes as a part of textwidthn, *I think*.

*Can I tell LaTeX to decrease my textwidth by the amount of space the marginnote takes so that my document is centered again including the note or is there any other solution to it?*

Problem: If I change the layout using the geometry package, non-standard pages like the TOC are changed as well.

**Idea: I'd like to use those notes as paragraph titles displayed at the side, like some textbooks do.**

MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\marginnote{Hello!}
\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can a *margin* note not be in a *margin*?

Comment: What you want is to change the outer margin. But what happens if some page does not have a margin note?

Comment: Haha, good point. I wanted to find a way to have kind of mini paragraph titles. The marginnote package seems to be the best guess - maybe there is another approach.

Comment: Yes, pages like the TOC should remain unchanged! However, it is perfectly right that *all* standard text pages are adjusted.

Comment: I am really not limited to the marginnotes package. I would just like to have those text elements at the side of the page.

Comment: `geometry` page can help you to format. Also, maybe you would have to use some package to create the TOC wider than the text width.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. However, it seems like a workaround since I would have to change back all other pages (toc, bibliography ...)?

Comment: You can use `mpinclude` as a global option to include the marginpar in the calculation of the textwidth.

Comment: @Johannes_B, very nice idea. I read about it in the scrbook manual. However, having it applied, only the header moved to the right while everything should have moved to the left ... something is not correct there.

Comment: @Johannes_B, actually in my MWE it works, but in my template it does not. Hmm ....

Comment: Your template might use `geometry` which does its own stuff. You need to alter the values for `marginparwidth` and the like as described in the geometry manual.

Comment: btw: This might be an XY-problem. You say you want this to have for some kind of paragraph title right at the end. Please elaborate on that, as the solution might be completely different from using `marginnote` for that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy with `geometry`; the `showframe` option is just for showing the various parts of the page.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{includemp,showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\marginnote{Hello! This is a long margin note to see what happens}
\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, @egreg! Two quick additions: (1) Do you know why includemp using geometry worked but mpinclude from scrbook didn't? (2) Can I exclude the option from certain pages such as the TOC?

Comment: Ah, of course I can, switching the setting back and forth. Perfect! :-)

Comment: @Tobias You can use `\newgeometry`.

Comment: @Tobias KOMA-script uses package `typearea` for calculating typearea and margins. As soon as you load package `geometry` it takes over and all the calculations and settings done by `typearea` are lost.

Answer (score 4):

My interpretation of the question:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{geometry,lipsum,calc}
\geometry{%
  a4paper,
  hcentering,
  textwidth=14cm,
  lines=52,
  includemp=true,
  showframe}

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\KOMAoptions{%
  headsepline, footsepline, plainheadsepline, plainfootsepline,
  headwidth=textwithmarginpar, footwidth=textwithmarginpar}

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{%
  hcentering,
  textwidth=14cm+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep,
  lines=52,
  ignoremp}

\tableofcontents \clearpage

\restoregeometry

\section{Introduction}
\noindent\marginpar{Hello!}%
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{Further introduction}
\subsubsection{Even further introduction}
\end{document}
```

[image]